# php pdo loop until number not found

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Think i'm having a mind block moment here! I have a table with data in as shown below:

```
id, Switch, ClusterID
1, sw1, 20
2, sw1, 21
3, sw1, 22
4, sw1, 24
```

I return the results of a `select all where sw1` using PDO and then want to loop through that until i find a ClusterID that's not in use.

I know that i can use a while loop to loop through until no result is found but just cant figure out how to place the code.

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: if a cluster id doesn't exist then there will be no row for the switch, I want to use any available number between 1 & 255 inclusive. Using blanks if there are any e.g. 1-20 then 23 would get used

Comment: That depends on the conditions, is a number smaller than 20 allowed, do you want to fill up holes in the list, do you just need the highest value, etc.

Comment: Why use a loop and not just `SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE Switch LIKE 'sw1' AND ClusterID LIKE '';` Then you get all `sw1` rows with empty `ClusterID`